# Jmeter - How many users should I be seeing

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-3.2

I am using Jmeter 3.2 to test an internal website with 4 thread groups in the test plan.  Each of the thread groups are testing different paths and the test plan is set to run all threads concurrently not consecutively.  I have each thread configured to run 6 threads, ramping up in 15 sec forever for 600 sec:

[image]

I am expecting to see a max of 24 users hitting the page at some point but I never see more than 12?  Is something off?

Comment: You should check which requests weren't sent.maybe something is disabled

Comment: I ran the test through jmeter alone and am seeing the correct number of users.  The issue looks to be related to Taurus and Blazemeter.  The runs triggered through that process look to be missing response calls.  The same test run in jmeter produced 96k targets while Taurus driven only reports 23k.